# Flexbox: Right Column should not be higher than Left one

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a 2 column layout with flexbox. The Left column has a dynamic height and should set the height of the full row, meaning the right row should be cut off and NOT increase the height of the parent container beyond this point.

However, how is this possible to achieve in a horizontal layout? Grow and shrink only affects the width, not the height.

Comment: Provide some code for solving ur issue

Comment: I'm not writing code, but working with a tool

Answer (score 0):

New solution (edited)

I don't think CSS alone can do that, because it always cascade from parents to children, therefore children cannot set the parent's height. This requires some JS (read the left child's height and then apply it to the parent)

```js
$(".container").height($(".left").height())
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: red solid 2px;
}
.container .left {
  width: 100px;
  border: green solid 3px;
}
.container .right {
  width: 100px;
  border: blue solid 3px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
  some text<br>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but i want the left columns height to be dynamic. so that the left column sets the rows height, and the row sets the right columns height.

Comment: ...which... isn't the case in my example?

Comment: left col has fixed height in your example

Comment: @JeremyThille If you add content to the right so it becomes higher than the left, it should get cut off when reaching the left columns height, which your solution doesn't

Comment: Ohhhhh OK I get it now. It's clearer when it's well explained :) Unfortunately I don't think CSS alone can do that, because it always cascade from parents to children, therefore children cannot set the parent's height. This requires some JS (read the left child's height and then apply it to the parent)

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working snippet.